# How do you view RowDataPacket from MySQL server w/ Angular?

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, ajax

I've search and none of other peoples questions directly match mine.

I'm using a simple GET request to pull MySQL table but it just returns some weird object on the client side. I console.log(rows) on the server side and it returns this:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
id: 1,
keyword: 'cannabis',
screenName: 'randeemckee',
numFollowers: 1526,
location: 'ÜT: 29.983699,-95.336676',
count: 1,
firstDate: Wed Apr 12 2017 19:19:34 GMT+0000 (UTC),
lastDate: Wed Apr 12 2017 19:19:34 GMT+0000 (UTC) } ]
```

Here is my client side code:

```
var dataApp = angular.module('dataApp', [])
.controller('databaseControl', dataControl);

dataControl.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataControl($http){
var dCtrl = this;

dCtrl.getData = function() {
    $http.get('/showdata')
        .then(function(success){
            console.log('Retreived database info!');
            console.log(success.data);



        }, function(error){
            console.log('Error retrieving data: ' + error);
        });
};
};
```

And here is my server side code:

```
app.get('/showdata', (req, res) => {
connection.query('SELECT * FROM twitterInfo', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        console.log(rows);
        res.send(req.body);
    };
});
});
```

Here is what the 'success.data' looks like on the client side:

```
Object {}
__proto__:Object 
constructor:function Object()
hasOwnProperty:function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable:function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString:function toLocaleString()
toString:function toString()
valueOf:function valueOf()
__defineGetter__:function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__:function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__:function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__:function __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__:function __proto__()
set __proto__:function __proto__()
```

This does not look decipherable and I just want to pull the data from the RowDataPacket and display it...

Answer (score 0):

Time to answer my own question...

It should be res.send(rows) NOT res.send(req.body);
I don't know why but hey it works.